# Python String Parts

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an easier way to find one part of a group of strings. Here's what I mean by that:

```
  word = ["Word", "Palabra"]
  If word == "Word":
    print word
```

So I need a way to detect if one of the strings equals "Word" without just looking for word[0] or word[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `in`.

```
your_list = ["Word", "Palabra"]    
if "Word" in your_list:
    print "Found!"
    DoSmth()
```

It means *if something is a part of something, return True, return False otherwise*.

Comment: To be slightly more accurate, I would say "if the sequence contains this element return `True`, else return `False`"